# My washer is filling up half way and then draining itself. I have tried to unplug it, restart and still the same results

Tags: repair, washing-machine

Kenmor 100 series washer is making a loud sound

Comment: Sounds like the drain hose is too low and fitted too tight into the plumbing, and is syphoning once the water rises high enough to start that flow...